# How do you get webdriverjs working?

Tags: javascript, testing, selenium

Anyone here have experience using Selenium and webdriverjs?  I'm coming from a non-Java background with a good deal of experience with Node.js and JavaScript in general.  According to the Selenium docs, you have to set-up a stand-alone Selenium server to use the node web driver.  Fortunately, they seem to be bundled together.

`npm install webdriverjs`

gets you the JAR file for the standalone selenium server inside the `node_modules/webdriverjs/bin` directory.  Example tests are inside the node `node_modules/webdriverjs/examples` directory but the tests in them fail when I run them from either the webdriverjs or examples directories.

What's the missing piece here?  What's the quickest way to get up and running?

I have read the docs.

Note: Stack overflow wouldn't let me use the tag webdriverjs, but this is specifically about webdriverjs, not using selenium with Java or other languages.

Update:  The only problem was that the built-in example tests are broken!

Comment: is there any error message indicates errors or blocking issue? as default, the webdrivejs uses the local selenium standalone server which listens to http://localhost:4444/wd/hub.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's what I did to get webdriverjs working:

Step 1: start selenium standalone in my laptop by running command `java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.33.0.jar`. then it will listen to `http://localhost:4444/` and you can access it via `http://localhost:4444/wd/hub/`. You also need to make sure Firefox browser is installed on your laptop.

Step 2: create a new directory and run command `npm install webdriverjs`.

Step 3: create a new file named `test_webdriverjs.js` in the new directory you created, and it looks like this:

```
var webdriverjs = require('webdriverjs');

var client = webdriverjs.remote({
    host: 'localhost',
    port: 4444
});

client.init();

client.url('https://github.com/')
  .getTitle(function(err, title) { console.log (title)}).call(function () {});

client.end();
```

Then run command `node test_webdriverjs.js` under the same directory and you will find it works. If it doesn't work, paste out the console output.

Comment: Interesting.  This got me up and going, and the issue was with the built-in mocha tests, not installation!

Your step zero is superfluous since as I said in the question, the webdriver npm package includes the standalone selenium server.  Here's the quickest way to get up and going:

Step one—Install webdriverjs: 
`npm install webdriverjs`
Step two—Run the stand-alone selenium server that was part of the install bundle:
`java -jar node_modules/webdriverjs/bin/selenium-server-standalone-2.31.0.jar`
Step 3—Use shawnzhu's test file; the built-in example tests are broken.