# JS/Node:- Selecting a tag using node.io

Tags: javascript, node.js, node.io

I am a beginner, and doing an assignment to scrape the content of this page using node.io
http://www.nycourts.gov/reporter/3dseries/2013/2013_06966.htm.

I want to save the text content which are under < P > tags as a string in a variable.

My code is this:

> var nodeio = require('node.io'); var methods = { 
>       input: false,
>       run: function() {
>           this.getHtml('http://www.nycourts.gov/reporter/3dseries/2013/2013_06966.htm',
>   function(err, $) {
>
> ```
>         //Handle any request / parsing errors
>         if (err) this.exit(err);
>
>
>          var content = $('P');
>
>          this.emit(content);
>     });
> } }
> ```
>
> exports.job = new nodeio.Job({timeout:10}, methods);

This is showing error: No elements matching 'P'. Please help..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got `Error: No elements matching 'P'` too when performing command:

```
$ ./node_modules/.bin/node.io query http://www.nycourts.gov/reporter/3dseries/2013/2013_06966.htm P
```

The root cause is no ending `</P>` in that page and node.io doesn't support auto correction for such malformed HTML like modern web browser. while it works well when querying `<blockquote>`:

```
$ ./node_modules/.bin/node.io query http://www.nycourts.gov/reporter/3dseries/2013/2013_06966.htm blockquote
```

However, you can make it by parsing HTML document over a real browser with [selenium](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/) technology.

Here's example javascript can run with node and a selenium grid on your host to get what you want. you can refer to my other answer to question [How do you get webdriverjs working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18324902/how-do-you-get-webdriverjs-working/18332581#18332581):

```
var webdriverjs = require('webdriverjs');

var client = webdriverjs.remote({
  host: 'localhost',
  port: 4444,
  desiredCapabilities: {
    browserName: 'safari', // you can change this accordingly
    version: '7',
    platform: "MAC"  // you can change this accordingly
  }
});

client.init();

client.url('http://www.nycourts.gov/reporter/3dseries/2013/2013_06966.htm')
  .getText("P",function(err, text) { console.log (text)}).call(function () {});

client.end();
```